# Битрикс, запрос в БД

Tags: php, битрикс

почему то не срабатывает, хотя вроде все по мануалам писал

```
 <?
    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
    // $APPLICATION->SetTitle("AJAX");
    CModule::IncludeModule('form');
    function getmaps()
    {
        $err_mess = (CForm::err_mess())."<br>Function: GetByID<br>Line: ";
        global $DB;

        $strSql = " SELECT * FROM maps ";
        $res = $DB->Query($strSql, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);
        return $res;
    }
    $maps = getmaps();
    echo json_encode($maps);
    // $APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();


    ?>
    <? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На AJAX страницах нет смысла подключать визуальные части header и footer.
Вместо
    `require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");`

пропишите 
`require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");`

Таким образом Вы подключите служебную часть пролога, то есть все функции битрикс, но не будет выводиться header.
Следовательно не придется применять

`$GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->RestartBuffer();`

Вместо

`require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");`

пропишите
`require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");`

Answer (score 2):

Если вы делаете страничку с Ajax ответом с использованием `echo json_encode($maps);` то вам нужно убрать включения  в виде

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");
```

Comment: А как тогда битрикс работать будет если его не подключить http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/js_lib/ajax/ 
Причем не в ajax проблема, а в том что результат пустой к какой бы таблице не обращался 
Ajax врубается $APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();

Comment: Надо подключать `'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php'`, он не содержит визуальной части

Answer (score 0):

Все дошло, нужно было еще fetch

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");

CModule::IncludeModule('form');
function getmaps()
{
    $err_mess = (CForm::err_mess())."<br>Function: getmaps<br>Line: ";
    global $DB;       
    $strSql = " SELECT F.* FROM maps F ";
    $res = $DB->Query($strSql, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);
    return $res;
}
$maps = getmaps();
$name_array=array();
while ($row = $maps->Fetch())
{
array_push($name_array, $row);
}
print_r($name_array);


?>
<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```

C Ajax выглядит так

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
 $GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->RestartBuffer();
CModule::IncludeModule('form');
function getmaps()
{
    $err_mess = (CForm::err_mess())."<br>Function: getmaps<br>Line: ";
    global $DB;
    // $DB = new CDatabase;
    // $where =  "ID = 20";
    $strSql = " SELECT * FROM maps LIMIT 0,20";
    $res = $DB->Query($strSql, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);

    $name_array=array();
    while ($row =  $res->Fetch())
    {
    array_push($name_array, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($name_array);
}
function getcategory()
{
    $err_mess = (CForm::err_mess())."<br>Function: getmaps<br>Line: ";
    global $DB;  
    $strSql = " SELECT * FROM maps_category";
    $res = $DB->Query($strSql, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);

    $name_array=array();
    while ($row =  $res->Fetch())
    {
    array_push($name_array, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($name_array);
}

if(!empty($_GET['maps'])){
    getmaps();
}
if(!empty($_GET['category'])){
    getcategory();
}

 die();

?>
<?  require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>
```